# issues updating WP database serialized options

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I am puzzled as I cannot update the 'active_plugins' serialized field with the following:
`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='a:2:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:21:"hello-dolly/hello.php";}' WHERE option_name='active_plugins'`

As you can see, I have tried to change the field with the same data originally contained in the 'active_plugins' field upon WP installation...
The mysql error is apparently due to the semi-colons in the field (when I take them out, - serialized data value notwithstanding, ogf course... - the query runs successfully !

Any clue ?

Many thanks.
JMB

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do that in PHP because of the serialized array.  You should make a function like this:

```
function update_my_plugins() {
$option = get_option('active_plugins'); // This will return you an array see below

$new_array = [
    'something here',
    'another something'
];

update_option('active_plugins', $new_array); // This will automatically reserialize

}
```

[image: Image of Array From get_option('active_plugins')]

From there, simply put this function in your footer.php and go hit your site.  It will fire when you visit your site and you can then take it out.

Comment: Hi mrwpress, & thanks for your help…
the aforementionned query is a PHP / MySQL query which I have meant to use outside of WP , as part of a larger app to manage WP websites…
What I don't get is why the data i post, which is exactly the same as the one originally stored in the WP wp_options / 'active_plugins' field, caused an error..
<br/>Apparently it's the semi-colon in the fields (eg part of the serialized data…- which causes that error..<br/>Can't figure out why !!!<br/ >THe issue is not so much th ebuild of the serialized data as it's recording in the DB…
Any thoughts ?

Comment: Query runs just fine for me copy and pasting from your above statement:

https://snipboard.io/OgMniJ.jpg

As you can see the only thing I changed was my database table prefix because I am not using 'wp_'.  You'r query works.  Maybe share how you are doing it in your code please.

Comment: hi and many thanks..the query is just  a copy paste of what i have in PHPmyAdmin..the issue seems to be the semi colons..dont understand why

Comment: I don't understand.  I have asked you for your code.  The query works.  *what* is wrong with the semicolons?  Please, articulate.

Comment: hi there...and thanks...<br/>the query, as stated above:<br/>UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='a:2:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:21:"hello-dolly/hello.php";}' WHERE option_name='active_plugins' <br/>as I mentionned, for some unexplained reason,the query, in a PHP script or in PhpMyAdmin, returns an error....the field type is obviously unchanged from the original xx_options table...<br/> Strangely..even if meaningless, When I take out the semi colons in the serialized data..no error and the field is recorded!

Comment: Semicolons in PHP are used for EOL connotation.  You will have to escape those ';' with backslashes.  So everywhere there is one in your string, use '\;'

Comment: hi and manu thanks!<br/>  Such a stupid issue...<br/> somehow got bogged in by this<br/>Tanks for toi patience and for re opening my eyes

Comment: Hi Again...<br/>Still does not work!!!<br/>The below shows an error when I run the query in PHPMyAdmin, and I don't understand why (it also returns an error in my PHP script...:<br/>UPDATE
    wor1865_options
SET
    option_value = 'a:2:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:21:"hello-dolly/hello.php";}'
WHERE
    option_name = 'active_plugins'

Answer (score 0):

Still does not work!!!
The below shows an error when I run the query in PHPMyAdmin, and I don't understand why (it also returns an error in my PHP script...:

```
UPDATE
    wor1865_options
SET
    option_value = 'a:2:{i:0;s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";i:1;s:21:"hello-dolly/hello.php";}'
WHERE
    option_name = 'active_plugins'
```

[image]
I really don't get it !!!